# Interpolate datetime into datepicker AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I've implemented [720kb's angular datepicker library](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker). It works really good, but when I try to set a date-min-limit, it doesn't work.

This is what I get when I try to set it programmatically (I also tried directly with a variable instead of a function):

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy/M/d" date-min-limit="{{ getMinDate() }}" class="ship_on_control">
```

Which generates this html object (note the double quotes)

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy/M/d" date-min-limit=""2016-10-05T19:18:15.418Z"" class="ship_on_control ng-isolate-scope">
```

This is my function on the controller:

```
$scope.getMinDate = function(){
            var yesterday = new Date();
            return yesterday;
        };
```

If I hardcode the date like so, it works:

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy/M/d" date-min-limit="2016-10-05T19:18:15.418Z" class="ship_on_control ng-isolate-scope">
```

What can I do to remove those additional quotes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't need interpolation...did you try without it?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it just puts the name of the function instead of its return value.

Comment: What is in your controller code?  Are you parsing the string as a date?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I've just updated my question. No, I'm just basically returning new Date() directly.